# Replace operators

Tags: replacement, operators

`/.` can be used to replace variables but how can one replace operators.

For example in `a * b`, `*` can be replaced by `+` or `x` or `/` etc. Is there some function to achieve this?

Comment: Answering your deleted comment.try `Fu[a_, b_, o_] := 
 Module[{}, Unevaluated[a + b] /. Plus -> o]; Fu[4, 2, Times] `

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Perhaps use the full names for the operators:

```
a * b /. Times -> Plus
```

> a + b

Answer (score 7):

`FullForm` prints the expression with no special syntax (e.g. `Plus` instead of `+`).

```
FullForm[a*b]
(* Times[a, b] *)
```

So you change the expression's head.

```
Table[fun @@ (a*b),
 {fun, {Plus, Subtract, Divide, Dot, Cross}}]
(* {a + b, a - b, a/b, a.b, a\[Cross]b} *)
```

Answer (score 3):

Just to complement: be careful when your symbols have values already assigned.
Compare:

```
a = 2; b = 3; rule = Plus -> Times;

a + b /. rule
ReleaseHold[Hold[a + b] /. rule]
Unevaluated[a + b] /. rule
Defer[a + b] /. rule
(*
 5
 6
 6
 a b
*)
```

Comment: `c = Defer[a + b];` How come `c + 3` doesn't return 8?

Comment: @BoLe: execute `c + 3 // FullForm` and see.